# Передача мета-функций в качества аргумента и особенности компиляции

Tags: c++, синтаксис, метапрограммирование

Нужно было написать мета-функцию `apply`, раскрывающую кортеж и вызывающую переданный функтор от элементов кортежа в качестве аргументов.

Пример использования функции:

```
auto f = [](int x, double y, double z) { return x + y + z; };
auto t = std::make_tuple(30, 5.0, 1.6);  // std::tuple<int, double, double>
auto res = apply(f, t);                // res = 36.6
```

С задачей я справился:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args, int... val>
auto apply_f(F f, std::tuple<Args...> t, IntList<val...>) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(std::get<val>(t))...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(std::get<val>(t))...);
}

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto apply(F f, std::tuple<Args...> t) -> decltype(apply_f(f, t, typename Generate<sizeof...(Args)>::type()))
{
    auto ans = apply_f(f, t, typename Generate<sizeof ...(Args)>::type());
    return ans;
}
```

Также проверяющая система использовала список интов `IntList` и мета-функцию `Generate<N>`, которая генерирует `IntList<0, 1, 2, ..., N - 1>`, с примерно следующей реализацией:

```
template<int ... ints>
struct IntList;

template<int H, int ... ints>
struct IntList<H, ints...>
{
    static const int Head = H;
    using Tail = IntList<ints...>;
};

template<>
struct IntList<> {};


template<int H, typename TL>
struct IntCons;

template<int H, int... values>
struct IntCons<H, IntList<values...>>
{
    using type = IntList<H, values...>;
};


template<size_t N, int K = 0>
struct Generate
{
    using type = typename IntCons<K, typename Generate<N - 1, K + 1>::type>::type;
};

template<int K>
struct Generate<0, K>
{
    using type = IntList<>;
};
```

Но это не так важно. Я не понимаю вот чего. Почему в функции `apply` нужно писать именно

`apply_f(f, t, typename Generate<sizeof ...(Args)>::type())`, а не

`apply_f(f, t, typename Generate<sizeof ...(Args)>::type)`. То есть зачем эти скобки после `type`? Как эти скобки помогают компилятору отработать правильно? Что они значат?

Comment: При вызове функции надо указывать ее аргументы. `type` является типом, а не значением. Соответственно `type()` создает новый экземпляр этого типа. То бишь скобки тут - это вызов конструктора при создании нового объекта. Кроме того, лучше использовать синтаксис list-initialization и писать `type{}`

Comment: @VTT Агаа, хорошо, спасибо. Вам, наверно, стоит написать это в виде ответа, чтобы я отметил его как правильный. А почему list-initialization лучше?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Про most vexing parse - это конечно правильное направление, но в вашем примере это по-прежнему вызов. Объявлением функции это было бы вот так `typename generate<sizeof...(args)>::type x();`.

Comment: @VTT Да, точно. :/